# Youtube api search with location retrieve error

Tags: youtube-api

I have the following request:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&location=+37.42307%2C-122.08427&locationRadius=1500mi&q=israel&access_token=ya29.CjHzAvvmL97PFzMkIopmF9nT4IVdznARs30XrE5i1_i6j3eQxBlbNdktch2iIHqz1-x7

And I receive the following error:

```
{
  error: {
    errors: [
      {
        domain: "youtube.search",
        reason: "invalidSearchFilter",
        message: "The request contains an invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions. Note that you must set the <code>type</code> parameter to <code>video</code> if you set a value for the <code>eventType</code>, <code>videoCaption</code>, <code>videoCategoryId</code>, <code>videoDefinition</code>, <code>videoDimension</code>, <code>videoDuration</code>, <code>videoEmbeddable</code>, <code>videoLicense</code>, <code>videoSyndicated</code>, or <code>videoType</code> parameters.",
        locationType: "parameter",
        location: ""
       }
     ],
     code: 400,
     message: "The request contains an invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions. Note that you must set the <code>type</code> parameter to <code>video</code> if you set a value for the <code>eventType</code>, <code>videoCaption</code>, <code>videoCategoryId</code>, <code>videoDefinition</code>, <code>videoDimension</code>, <code>videoDuration</code>, <code>videoEmbeddable</code>, <code>videoLicense</code>, <code>videoSyndicated</code>, or <code>videoType</code> parameters."
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message say you have to define the `type` parameter to `video`.

So your call must be something like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&location=37.42307,22.08427&locationRadius=50km&q=israel&access_token=ya29.CjHzAvvmL97PFzMkIopmF9nT4IVdznARs30XrE5i1_i6j3eQxBlbNdktch2iIHqz1-x7&type=video

Also, the API does not support `locationRadius` parameter values larger than 1000 kilometers, so you have to define a smaller than 1500mi.(**[Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters)**)

You can test all the parameters **[here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&location=37.42307,22.08427&locationRadius=50km&q=israel&type=video)**

Last but not least don't upload public your `access_token`. It is supposed to be secret. You have to change it now since you made it public, or someone can use it for his own needs